# IO in C standard

Tags: c, io

The following program is from a homework assignment. 
I need to write a program where it:

asks a Seed and a Range,

generates and displays a sequence of random numbers based on the seed and range input,

converts the above into a sequence of "A"s, "B"s, or "C"s depending on the generated sequence: turn 1 into A, 2 into B, 3 into C;

asks whether to continue; if user puts "n", stop; else starts over again.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int seed;
    int Range;
    char ch;

    while (ch != "n") {
        printf("Enter a seed: ");
        scanf("%d", &seed);
        printf("Enter a Range: ");
        scanf("%d", &Range);

        srand(seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            scheduler(rand() % Range + 1);
        }

        printf("Continue?\n");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I put two arbitrary numbers and it generates a random sequence as expected. But then it just prints "Continue?" without taking an input from me and then asks me to enter a seed. What's wrong with my code? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: use         `scanf(" %c", &ch);`(not space before `%c`) because `%c` was reading `\n` from previous input.

Comment: Also, `ch` is uninitialized when you use it as the conditional in your while loop.  Try using do...while loop instead.  Also, you are comparing a `char` to a `char *` there.  instead it should be `ch != 'n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

in order to eat the leftover character (the newline character you pressed when you entered the numbers (`seed and`Range`) before).

I had wrote more about that issue [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/).

---

Moreover, your code invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB), since you check `ch` before it gets initialized here:

```
char ch;

while (ch != "n") {
    ...
}
```

Use a do-while loop structure instead, like this:

```
do {
    ...
} while (ch != 'n');
```

---

Furthermore, you should get a compiler warning like this:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while (ch != "n") {
               ^~
warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

Change `"n"` to `'n'`, since `ch` is of type `char`, not `char*`.

---

Putting everything together, your code should like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int seed;
    int Range;
    char ch;

    do {
        printf("Enter a seed: ");
        scanf("%d", &seed);
        printf("Enter a Range: ");
        scanf("%d", &Range);

        srand(seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            scheduler(rand() % Range + 1);
        }

        printf("Continue?\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    } while (ch != 'n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The third point you make is interesting but not clear. Can you elaborate on that pls? Thnx

Comment: @Zhiwei Liu 'n' is a char. "n" is a string (it's type char*). Since ch is of type char. As a result you should use 'n' for the comparison, and not "n".  Since my answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept my answer, by clicking on the green mark at it's left.

Comment: You mention that I would get this : warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while (ch != "n") {
               ^~              I don't see any pointer or integer Also, isn't char* supposed to be a pointer to a character?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int seed;
   int Range;
   char ch = '\0';    /* initialize ch to something other than 'n' */

   /* if ch not initialized, u take your chances on being able to enter while loop */
   while (ch != 'n')    / single quote characters, double quote for strings imply null character \0 after last character in string */
   {
       printf("Enter a seed: ");
       fflush( stdout );   /* because of no \n in printf */
       scanf("%d", &seed);
       printf("Enter a Range: ");
       fflush( stdout );   /* because of no \n in printf */
       scanf("%d", &Range);

       srand(seed);

       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           scheduler(rand() % Range + 1);
       }

       printf("Continue?\n");   /* bet u this works, because of \n */
       scanf("%c", &ch);
   }

   return 0;
```

}